# For which $a, b$ in $(-1,1)$ does $\frac{1}{3}x^3-a^2x+b=0$ have three real solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, cubics

I know $\frac{1}{3}x^3-a^2x+b=0$ will always have one solution as $\frac{-b}{x} = \frac{1}{3}x^2-a^2$ will always have one intersection in the upper two quadrants of the coordinate system.

But I can't really make out for the bottom two quadrants.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The number of a real solutions for the equation $x^3+3px+2q=0$ is in relation to the sign of discriminant $D=q^2+p^3$. Above equation will have **3 real distinct solutions** if $D<0$!

Comment: That's something I didn't know actually, thanks

Comment: According to [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_3), the discriminant of your equation is actually $D=-108(q^2+p^3)$.

Comment: I found my answer in this handbook (page 40): https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540721222

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean "distinct real solutions for real $x$", since otherwise the question is boring:  any degree three polynomial has three complex roots counted with multiplicity.

The [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_3) of this cubic is $\frac{1}{3}(4a^6 - 9b^2)$.  The cubic has three distinct real roots if the discriminant is positive, which requires $4a^6 > 9 b^2$.  This region is indicated in this plot.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(Note that the boundary of the shaded regions is *not* suitable choices of $(a,b)$.  For instance, $(a,b) = (0,0)$ does not yield three distinct solutions.)

Comment: Is there a way to calculate this blue area (with the use of an integral)?

Comment: @Student : Yes.  I'd compute the area in one quadrant, then multiply by $4$.  You should have no trouble showing $b < \frac{2}{3}a^3$, so you want the area between the $a$-axis and $\frac{2}{3}a^3$ for $0 \leq a < 1$.